Help with Arcing a Mesh
So, I followed this tutorial and went awry at some point. How do I correct the jagged edges to make it look like a proper axe?

Solution 1.
I just quickly modeled something similar to yours.

Select these edge loops.

Dissolve them using Ctrl X.

Add an edge loop in the middle and scale it down on the Z axis.

Bevel the edge loop.

Solution 2:
Find a reference image, import it into Blender, and adjust the vertices manually to match your reference.

